# I need to get the total number of Null values from multiple columns of a table

Tags: sql, pyspark

example table:

```
color|country|value1|value2|value3
-----------------------------------
Red  | India |1     |null  |4
Blue | USA   |4     |2     |null
Red  | USA   |null  |1     |2
Blue | null  |4     |1     |1
```

Output:

```
Target | No_1 | No_2 | No_4 | No_null
value1 | 1    | 0    | 2    | 1
value2 | 2    | 1    | 0    | 1
value3 | 1    | 1    | 1    | 1
```

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: What rdbms? sql just language..

Comment: I get know idea on the approach for writing it in SQL.. please advise..

Comment: in an aggregate function you can have a `SUM` and in the argument do the null checkings. Something similar to `SUM(case condition_col1 end + case condition_col1 end)`

Comment: Conditional SUM in sql has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sum+conditional+%5Bsql%5D) multiple times, check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UNION ALL` and then `CASE WHEN` for conditional aggregation

```
select 
    target, 
    count(case when val=1 then 1 end) as no_1,
    count(case when val=2 then 1 end) as no_2,
    count(case when val=4 then 1 end) as no_4,
    count(case when val is null then 1 end) as no_null
from
(
   select 'value1' as target,value1 as val from tablename
   union all
   select 'value2',value2 from tablename
   union all
   select 'value3', value3 from tablename
)X group by target
```

Comment: All data is in the same table, no need to a union but an unpivot

Comment: @bradbury9, from my understanding union all required as valueas are in separate column

Comment: I agree, got confused